# Excel pivot table doesn't calculate sum correctly

Tags: excel

I am working on Excel. It has Date, Amount and Category fields. The following is the data

```
Date       Amount     Category
02/17/17   -$150      Cleaning
02/13/17   -$150      cleaning
02/03/17   -$150      cleaning
```

I did  a pivot table to calculate the sum of the amount by selecting all dates of February. But the sum comes as -$300 instead of -$450. When I looked under "Show Details" for the sum, it has used only values under 02/17 and 02/13 but not for 02/03. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: probably excel undestood data "02/03" as 2 march.... Use function month to check it....

Comment: You've probably selected 1 row too few in your range when you created the pivot table. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t7tvhns_jfZXs8LewWl-bcm4ihmCUn4JedRpIyIyms8/edit?usp=sharing